# Gunicorn Timeout Server Slow issues

Tags: python, django, nginx, webserver, gunicorn

I have deployed a webapplication Python Django Rest Framework Front end is Vue js and Database is Mysql.

Hosted the website on digital ocean i am using CPU Optimized Droplets with the below configuration 8 GB 4 vCPUs i facing performance issue the site is very slow though the hosting is CPU optimized with 8gb of ram.

When i checked the error log i am able to find [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:9116) i increased the timeout time of the gunicorn still i am facing the same issue.

1)I want to increase the performance 
2)I want to fix the timeout issue i have increased the value in gunicorn as nginx the maximum value is 75s i have not done any addition to it. what will be th best solution.

Kindly help me is there any alternative ways to test the performance of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need optimization

Tips on optimizing your django rest on production server .

1. Check your queries. Best way to check this is using the django debug toolbar, it will show how many queries you produce and if you think there is a lot, then optimize your queries. Ex. use prefetch_related or  select_related to join the tables or else it will query one by one.
2. Index your tables, try to index the columns you're always using on querying. Just be careful on indexing, just index the columns you really wanted because the downside will be slower on update, delete and add.
3. Check your database health, if you perform delete or update frequently those data actually stored somewhere and it is still part of your indexes, it called **Dead Rows**, you can remove this by perform some commands like **vacuum** if your are using postgres.
4. Scale up your server, this actually depends on the request/traffic of your server, check the RAM or CPU spikes for you to determine the needed units. As experience, I have atleast 10m row of data on some of my tables, which in some scenario I cross refer it to a 30k data, on 2gb RAM and 1gb CPU working fine in few simultaneous request.